# CSS3 layout with fixed left column and flex right hand column within a fixed container

Tags: css

Just wondering if this is possible for css, i am try to have a layout where left hand column have a fixed width and right hand side have a flex width within a contain of fixed width.

here is the attachment for image

[image]

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/gUJ98/)?

Comment: @Harry Thanks not really the right hand side would be nice to be fluid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jFJlK) can help you

HTML

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="left">Test</div>
  <div class="right">Test</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
*{margin: 0}
.outer {
  max-width: 1444px;
}
.left {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 600px;
  background: red
}
.right {
  margin-left: 200px;
  background: yellow;
  height: 600px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works under your demo link, so basically just width to be auto?

Comment: You need to give float: left and width: 200px to left sidebar and margin-left: 200px to right content.

Comment: Thanks Tushar have a look at harry example, he didn't have a margin-left: 200px, but it looks like still works.

Comment: Yes you are right harry has not given margin-left because of which its .flexible start from the same point where .fixed-left starts. margin left is needed to move .flexible where .fixed-left ends.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a table for sure.  Not sure if anyone has a better/alternate method.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.container { width:400px; }
.left { width:100px; background-color:red;}
.right { width:100%; background-color:yellow;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table class="container">
<tr>
<td class="left">left section</td>
<td class="right">right section</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: thanks ben hmmm... table is hard to deal with responsive design i will try to avoid if i can. thanks anyhow mark you up for one of the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by using the following code. Basically we are floating the left side div with fixed width and letting the right side div take up the rest.

**HTML:**

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='fixed-left'>abcd</div>
    <div class='flexible'>12345</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container{
    border: 1px solid black;
    max-width: 440px;
}
.fixed-left{
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
.flexible{
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gUJ98/)|[**Demo without Margin**](http://jsfiddle.net/gUJ98/1/)

Comment: Thanks harry, apologise my English may be not very clear... :)

Comment: interesting he is actually got a margin-left: 200px; (on the right hand side column) which is kind smart... not sure should i include that margin-left or not, because without it still works (which is your example)

Comment: That depends on how you want the layout to work on very low resolutions (less than or equal to 200px). With the margin, the right content will always leave a space of 200px in front whereas without it, the right will simply wrap around to next line and start from the left edge. You can see that in [this sample](http://jsfiddle.net/gUJ98/1/).

Comment: Thanks harry I wish I can give 2 ticks... cause both are awesome answer.

Comment: @bluebill1049: Never mind mate. SO says very clearly that the choice of acceptance is yours. You should accept whichever answer you preferred :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use float for that:
HTML:

```
<div class="left-div">This is left DIV with lots of text text text text<br />and even more text</div>
<div class="right-div">
    <div class="upper">This is upper right DIV</div>
    <div class="lower">This is lower right DIV</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.left-div {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}

.right-div {
    float: right;
}

.upper {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.lower {
    max-width: 1444px;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/68u8N/

Comment: Thanks but it need to wrapper around a container. maybe my picture is not clear enough